# weird issue with root.destroy() not working with .bind()

Tags: python, tkinter, destroy

There seems to be a rather weird issue with the code I've been developing regarding tkinter's `root.destroy()` method. It just doesn't seem to want to work with the `.bind()` method. The other two bind functions works properly when changing the images, but `root.destroy` just doesnt work regardless of how I tried to put it. I've tried putting it in a function and calling it, putting it in an anonymous function and replacing it with `self.master.destroy`, nothing seems to work. The one that was called by the button does tho, only the key binding does not. Would appreciate some help on the matter, below is my code:

```
class ImageFrame:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("Nothing sus move along")
        #root.geometry("1920x1080")
        master.config(bg="black")
        master.resizable(False,False)
        master.columnconfigure([0,3],weight=1)
        master.rowconfigure([0,3],weight=1)
        self.leftRightFrame = Frame(height=300)
        self.leftRightFrame.grid(row=2,column=1)
        self.image=Label(master, image=images[page])
        self.image.grid(row=2,column=2)
        self.nxtbtn = Button(self.leftRightFrame, text="Next(D)", bg='black', fg='red', width=5, font=('ariel 10 bold'), relief=GROOVE, command=self.snext)
        self.nxtbtn.pack(side=TOP,ipady=50)
        self.image.bind('d',self.snext)
        self.backbtn = Button(self.leftRightFrame, text="Back(A)", bg='black', fg='red', width=5, font=('ariel 10 bold'), relief=GROOVE, command=self.sback)
        self.backbtn.pack(side=BOTTOM,ipady=50)
        self.image.bind('a',self.sback)
        self.exitbtn = Button(master, text="Exit(Esc)", bg='black', fg='red', width=5, font=('ariel 10 bold'), relief=GROOVE, command=root.destroy)
        self.exitbtn.grid(row=2,column=3)
        self.image.bind('q',lambda e: root.destroy)
        self.image.focus_set()
    def snext(self,e):
        global page
        page+=1
        if page>len(images)-1:
            page=0                                 
        self.image.configure(image = images[page%len(images)])
    def sback(self,e):
        global page
        page-=1
        if page<0:
            page=0
        self.image.configure(image = images[page%len(images)])
    def endwin(self,e):
        self.master.destroy
        print('Window terminated')

root = Tk()
mainWindow = ImageFrame(root)
root.mainloop()
```

The unrelated parts regarding image processing have been removed

Comment: if you want to `__call__` an object or function you need to add `()`, so `self.master.destroy()` should do what you want. Same with `self.image.bind('q',lambda e: root.destroy())`. While in the case of the button `command=root.destroy` there is a reference to a function that will be called by the button instance if the *click event* occur.

Comment: Try launching your program from a terminal or cmd.exe. Then you can see any exceptions that are produced.